# How to choose an inductor for a LCL filter?

Tags: pwm, filter, inductance

I am trying to make a voltage generator. I used an inverter and it is controlled by a PWM signal. I used a LCL filter to filter the output signal since it is rich in harmonics but in the choice of inductance I found a problem. It is necessary that this inductor is of value 3.9 mH, supports a current of 3 A, and has only 2 pins. The problem is that all the inductors that I find have 4 pins. Is there a problem for me if I use this type of inductor and in the common mode branch are there any undesirable effects on the current or the characteristics of the inductor?

Inductor datasheet: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/400/b82725s2-1527604.pdf

[image]

Here is the electrical schematic:

[image]

Here is the simulation:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to link to the inductor data sheet. Not all 3.9 mH inductors are equal and it's likely that those that you chose are not suitable for common terminal configurations because there cores will heavily saturate.

Comment: inductance datasheet:https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/400/b82725s2-1527604.pdf

Comment: That's a common mode choke you are using in a differential mode fashion. It will saturate immediately. Also, it's unknown what you are trying to filter out in the first place. Try it with a similator first. What does your PWM circuit look like?

Comment: here I am changing my question

Comment: Old, I know, but still.. I'm not sure what the OP's problem was/is in finding a 2 terminal 3.9mH inductor.  In less than 5 min I found the DENO-25-0001 at Mouser.  4mH(+/- 15%), 16A+, 27mOhm.  It's designed as a Ground Line choke, and so it should work  here. Yes, it's a "4mH" and not a 3.9, but in this case I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy aka and winny have pointed out using common mode chokes in this application is not suitable.

Explanation:
As common mode chokes are used normally the core material needs to handle only the **difference of magentic fields** created by current going one way in the upper coil and the other way in the lower coil. Only if this current **difference** (may be some 10mA) is too large the core material will be saturated.

I.e. even if the common mode choke is rated for 3 A, it will be almost useless if too much current (some 10mA; much less than 3A) is going the same direction through both sub-coils (or only through one of them).

Comment: so what is the type of inductor that should be used in this situation?

Comment: If you pick one that has only 2 (instead of 4) terminals you can be sure that it is not a common mode choke; and of course it needs to be rated for the current and frequency in your application. It might be quite large and expensive...

Comment: I can not find one that has only 2 with a value of 3.9 mH.

Comment: Maybe you find some inductors originally made for audio applications, that are suitable for your purpose. That's what I've found: https://www.falconacoustics.co.uk/audio-inductors-ferrite-air-core-iron-dust/audio-inductors-4mh-6mh-ferrite-air-core-iron-dust.html